# Python - While True Loop until Condition is met

Tags: python

I need some help to complete this Loop Function please. I need this function to check if the Server is in RUNNING state. If it is in RUNNING state it will exit. If the server is in STARTING sate, it will print STARTING sate and again check the state until the server is in RUNNING state.

Once the server is in RUNNING sate it will print 'the server is in RUNNING state' and exit the loop.

The server will take upto 8 minutes to come up in RUNNING state depending upon installed components, libraries and classes. In some cases it may take more time, but I dont want to limit to 8 minutes for the loop.

The maximum time can be 10minutes. After 10 minutes if it is still not in RUNNING state, then we can exit the loop and print 'problem starting the server'.

```
def wait():
    acu=0
    while True:
        #serverStatus(deploymentTarget)
        appflag=0
        if state(deploymentTarget,'Server')=='RUNNING':
            appflag=1
        elif state(deploymentTarget,'Server')=='STARTING':
            appflag=2

        if appflag == 1 :
          # If appflag has value 1, it means that the server is active, so we exist the loop.
            break
        else :
            if appflag == 2 and (acu<30):
               serverState = serverStatus(deploymentTarget)
               java.lang.Thread.sleep(10000)
               acu = acu +1
               break
```

Thanks

Comment: and what you want? Any questions?

Comment: I think there is some indebtation issues, please clear it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep

def wait()
    acu = 0
    while not state(deploymentTarget,'Server')=='RUNNING' and (acu < 30):
        acu += 1
        if state(deploymentTarget,'Server')=='STARTING':
            print("the server is starting")
        sleep(10)
    if state(deploymentTarget,'Server')=='RUNNING':
        print("the server is running")
    else:
        print('problem starting the server')
```

<strike>By the way, you shouldn't mix java commands into your python program.</strike>

Comment: If you're using Jython then using java commands is perfectly fine.

Comment: okay, didn't think about that. Just for curiosity: Would it be wise to use Javas sleep here instead of the python equivalent? I can imagine that this would result in avoidable overhead..

Comment: Hi Daniel, if you think that using Java would be better than Python, I can try that. Please update this post. Thanks...

Comment: Hi, no I didn't say that! I wasn't aware that you can freely mix Java and Python commands when using Jython. However, I was concerned that this could result in performance losses. By thinking about it I guess that it doesn't matter since it would only play a role during compilation.

Comment: Hi Deniel, Could you please to complete this script. The script works but it does not stop when the server is in RUNNING state. Could you please update the script to stop when the server is in RUNNING state during loop. Thanks, Harish.

Comment: Hi, could you try again?